# After defining ButterKnife , Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory error

Tags: android, android-manifest, butterknife

I have a problem about android manifest file in my android project after adding ButterKnife dependency in gradle file.

When I run the program, it throws an error shown below.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-21:19 to override.
```

Here is my file.

```
<application
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:label,android:roundIcon,android:supportsRtl,android:theme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // TODO 1) ButterKnife Library Defined
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use butterknife:10.x.x unless you also migrated to AndroidX. If you haven't migrated, you'll need to stick to 9.0.0 for now. Once you migrate, then you can update to 10.1.0 (or whatever is latest at that time). –